# Why list is unchanged?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had the following code:

```
s=['big','smas']
s[-1]+'h'
```

My hope is to change `s` to be `['big','small']`. That code failed. So I changed the code to:

```
s=['big','smas']
s[-1]=s[-1]+'h'
```

This works.
I don't get why the first code is incorrect.

In addition to `s[-1]=s[-1]+'h'`, is there any other way to change `s` to `['big','smash']`?

Comment: string are immutable in python. once created you can't modify them. so in first case you are creating string but not assigning it's value to something.

Comment: Strings are immutable. you can't be modified. you need to recreate it, it works for s[-1] = because with = assignment you are recreating it.

Comment: `x+1` doesn't change `x` either. Why would it?

Comment: this have nothing to do with the data type of the element in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The first code computes a new string, that is a concatenation of the two parts, but it does not assign its result anywhere.

The second code does the same thing, but then it puts the new string in the list.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words : in your first code you are 'missing' an assignment (=) sign , meaning it will do the operation but assign it to nowhere.

In your second code you are doing it correctly and assign the changed string to you `s` list.